# Define a list variable

Tags: lists, etoolbox

I am using `etoolbox` for list processing, specifically `\forcsvlist`.

When passing the comma-separated list directly to `\forcsvlist`, it is able to parse each item in the list. However, if I define the list variable somewhere else, `\forcsvlist` is not able to distinguish between each item in the list, and takes it as one whole argument.

Eg:

```
\newcommand\doforme[1]{#1 \\}
\forcsvlist\doforme{a,b,c}
```

Above code works perfectly adding newline to end of each item.
But following code doesn't work

```
\newcommand\doforme[1]{#1 \\}
\def\@authors{a,b,c}
\forcsvlist\doforme{\@authors}
```

This makes me think that there must be some other way to define the list that `\forcsvlist` can interpret.

Answer (score 4):

The problem in using the variable form was its earlier expansion which would then take the whole `a,b,c` as one entity. By one entity, I mean the only single element in the list.

To solve this problem, first of all we need to use double brackets here. So `{a,b,c}` becomes `{{a,b,c}}`, the reason of which will become clear by the end of this answer.

`\expandafter` primitive expands the argument given to it after the next one. For example, if there are `\def\foo{A}, \def\bar{B}` and `\expandafter\foo\bar`, it will first become `\foo B`, and then eventually becomes `AB`.

Similarly, I can solve the above problem in the question like this :

```
noindent\expandafter\forcsvlist\expandafter\doforme\authors
```

If we take a look at above recursive expression, the first expandafter goes to its first argument (\forcsvlist), skips it for a while, and try expanding argument next to it which in this case is again `\expandafter`. So, the second `\expandafter` again skips `\doforme` for a while and then expands `\authors.` `\authors` is currently `{{a,b,c}}`. After expansion it becomes `{a,b,c}`. So the final expression now becomes

```
\noident\forcsvlist\doforme{a,b,c}
```

which is equivalent to passing the argument like the first case in the question, and hence produce same results.

Answer (score 4):

The package `etoolbox` defines a special command to handle internal lists: `\forlistloop`. These lists use a special character as internal list separator. So you have to use `\listadd` (or similar commands - see the [`etoolbox` documentation](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox)) to add an item to such a list.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\begin{document}
\newcommand\doforme[1]{#1 \\}
\forcsvlist{\listadd\authors}{a,b,c}
\noindent\forlistloop\doforme{\authors}
\end{document}
```