# recursive list type like definition in LaTeX

Tags: macros, etoolbox

I'm trying to typeset an OCaml like list and would like to define a command `mylist` for it. The expected result is something like below:

```
\mylist{}          -->     []
\mylist{aa}        -->     [aa]
\mylist{aa,bb}     -->     [aa;bb]
\mylist{aa,bb,cc}  -->     [aa;bb;cc]
```

I expect that `,` is always the typed separator (in LaTeX) but is displayed as another sign (here it is `;`) in the pdf document (it's acceptable to hardcode the displayed one in `mylist` definition).

After searching for a while I found [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/54878/6466) and changed it a bit.

```
\newcounter{listcount}\newcounter{totalcount}%
\newcommand{\mylist}[1]{%
  \setcounter{totalcount}{0}% Reset total count
  \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{\stepcounter{totalcount}}% Reconfigure count
  \docsvlist{#1}% Count number of items
  \setcounter{listcount}{0}% Reset current item count
  \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{% Reconfigure item \do
    \stepcounter{listcount}% Next item
    ##1;\ifnum\value{listcount}<\value{totalcount}\,\fi% Print item
  }
  \left[\docsvlist{#1}\right]% Process list
}
```

The problem is that when the list contains >1 elements, there is a trailing `;`.

```
\mylist{aa,bb} --> [aa;bb;]
```

Intuitively there is a need to test whether the element is the last one. However I seem lost in the macro definition w.r.t. `listcount` and the number of commas.

I also found [a use of `forcsvlist`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/240025/6466) but the problem is similar. There seems [a solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101312/command-with-variable-number-of-arguments-to-format-menu-sequences) by using other packages, but a bit overkill so I tend not to use that.

Comment: Can't you deal with the first item as a special case and then add your semicolon **before** each other item. Then you only need to test for item 1.

Comment: I used `\listadd` etc. in earlier times and switched to `\seq` lists from `expl3` -- it's **much** easier and not really overkill ;-)

Comment: @PaulStanley yes, that's a solution but i don't know about the syntax to extract the "head" of the list ...

Comment: @ChristianHupfer i know quite little about LaTeX and `expl3`. Can you elaborate that?

Comment: Can't you forget your first counting loop and simply change your ifnum test to less than 1 (moving the counter increment to after it)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The character `;` must be shifted to be placed inside of the `\ifnum\value....\fi` test.

I also added a **much, much, much** shorter `expl3` version right before `\begin{document}`, although the `expl3` syntax might be very strange to L3 newbies...

I used the `\docsvlist` and `\forcsvlist` macros up to two years (2015) ago, but shifted then to he much more powerful `expl3` syntax (although not easy to learn), especially for the multitude of lists there are in `expl3`, such as `seq` or `clist` or `prop` lists, which provide more functionality, in my point of view.

But first to the `\ifnum...` test:

```
 \ifnum\value{listcount} < \value{totalcount}
 ;\,
 \fi
```

just tests whether the current value of the `listcount` counter is smaller than the value of `totalcount` counter and prints a `;\,` then, otherwise it doesn't.

The `expl3` version is at the end and much simpler in its usage, no tests are needed (in fact, they are hidden behind `\seq_use`).

First enter the `expl3` - syntax style with `\ExplSyntaxOn` and store the comma separated list values of the argument to a temporary sequence variable `\l_tmpa_seq`. Later display this list with `\seq_use:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {;\,}` -- the command takes care about the end of the list.

In order to prevent space gobbling, the wrapper command `\displaylist` is defined outside, see also 
[Spaces in l3prop](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/364622/spaces-in-l3prop/364623#364623) for the topic of spaces with `expl3`.

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcounter{listcount}
\newcounter{totalcount}%
\newcommand{\mylist}[1]{%
  \setcounter{totalcount}{0}% Reset total count
  \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{\stepcounter{totalcount}}% Reconfigure count
  \docsvlist{#1}% Count number of items
  \setcounter{listcount}{0}% Reset current item count
  \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{% Reconfigure item \do
    \stepcounter{listcount}% Next item
    ##1\ifnum\value{listcount}<\value{totalcount};\,\fi% Print item
  }
  \left[\docsvlist{#1}\right]% Process list
}


\begin{document}
$\mylist{aa,bb,cc}$

$\mylist{aa}$


\end{document}
```

Of course `$\mylist{}$` will yield `[]`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\newcommand{\myotherlist}[1]{%
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_tmpa_seq  {#1}
  \displaylist{\seq_use:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {;\,}}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\newcommand{\displaylist}[1]{%
  \left[#1\right]%
}

\begin{document}

$\myotherlist{}$

$\myotherlist{aa,bb,cc}$

$\myotherlist{aa}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh that works! sorry the syntax is really greek to me (i know how to say in other program languages but not in LaTeX)...

Comment: can you explain a bit about the \ifnum syntax. I googled a while but haven't found an easy-to-understand tutorial. really a noob question...

Comment: @HongxuChen: Done.

Comment: so basically `\myotherlist` just does a replacement? I think I will still  stick to the previous solution since LaTeX3 syntax is difficult for me and I don't know how to get started to customize myself.

Comment: @HongxuChen: Yes, `\myotherlist` provides the same functionality but I could not name it `\mylist` again, of course

Answer (score 11):

Here is an alternative solution which does not need to iterate the list twice. After the first element, the `\do` is replaced by `\mydo`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand*{\mydo}[1]{;\,#1}

\newcommand{\mylist}[1]{%
  \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{##1\let\do\mydo}%
  \left[\docsvlist{#1}\right]% Process list
}

\begin{document}

$\mylist{aa,bb,cc}$

$\mylist{aa}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: actually I prefer this solution:-)

Answer (score 8):

A fully expandable version:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\ocamllist}[1]{\left[\ocaml@list#1,,\@nil}
\def\ocaml@list#1,#2,#3\@nil{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo % no comma
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
  {\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\,\else#1\fi\right]}
  {#1;\ocaml@list#2,#3,\@nil}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$\ocamllist{}$

$\ocamllist{aa}$

$\ocamllist{aa,bb}$

$\ocamllist{aa,bb,cc}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Not expandable, but more compact:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\ocamllist}{m}
 {
  \left[
  \clist_set:Nn \l_hongxu_ocamllist_clist {#1}
  \clist_if_empty:NTF \l_hongxu_ocamllist_clist
   { \, }
   { \clist_use:Nn \l_hongxu_ocamllist_clist {;} }
  \right]
 }
\clist_new:N \l_hongxu_ocamllist_clist
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$\ocamllist{}$

$\ocamllist{aa}$

$\ocamllist{aa,bb}$

$\ocamllist{aa,bb,cc}$

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

May be I have not understood the problem, but instead of getting dizzy counting the items of the list and so... why not just take the argument as one string where you must replace the commas by semicolons?

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xstring}
\def\mylist#1{\ensuremath{\mathbin{[\StrSubstitute{#1}{,}{;}]}}}
\begin{document}

\mylist{}           

\mylist{aa}         

\mylist{aa,bb}      

\mylist{aa,bb,cc}   

\end{document}
```

Comment: really nice package!

Answer (score 4):

Here is an expanable solution using only TeX primitives:

```
\def\ocamlist#1{\ocamlistA #1,,}
\def\ocamlistA#1,{[#1\ocamlistB}
\def\ocamlistB#1,{\ifx,#1,#1]\else;#1\expandafter\ocamlistB\fi}

$\ocamlist{aa,bb}$

\end
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `listofitems` approach.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\newcommand\mylist[1]{%
  [\ifx\relax#1\relax\else
  \readlist*\MyList{#1}%
  \foreachitem\i\in\MyList{\ifnum\icnt>1;\fi\i}\fi]%
}
\begin{document}
\mylist{}

\mylist{aa}

\mylist{aa,bb}

\mylist{aa,bb,cc}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If the space following the punctuation is important,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\newcommand\mylist[1]{%
  [\ifx\relax#1\relax\else
  \readlist*\MyList{#1}%
  \foreachitem\i\in\MyList{\ifnum\icnt>1; \fi\i}\fi]%
}
\begin{document}
\mylist{}

\mylist{aa}

\mylist{aa,bb}

\mylist{aa,bb,cc}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This falls under [Cunning (La)TeX tricks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/89187/5764):

> [aa;bb;cc]
>   [aa]
>   []
>   [aa:bb:cc:dd]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\mylist}[2][;]{%
  \def\itemdelim{\def\itemdelim{#1}}% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/89187/5764
  \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{\itemdelim##1}%
  [\docsvlist{#2}]% Process list
}

\begin{document}

\mylist{aa,bb,cc}

\mylist{aa}

\mylist{}

\end{document}
```

The principle is similar to [Thomas' answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/360962/5764) and delays the setting of `\itemdelim` by a single iteration, `\def`ining it as a (re)definition. This way, at it's *first* use, it redefines `\itemdelim` without setting anything. Subsequent uses (if they exist) will actually set `\itemdelim`.