# Spaces in l3prop

Tags: expl3, l3prop

How can one store **verbatim** code in a LaTeX3 property list?

My goal is to store person names in a property inside a property list. This means that both accents and spaces must be stored in the key `name`. Here's my code:

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\prop_new:N \aaa
\prop_put:Nnn \aaa {name} {Alfr\'ed R\'enyi}
\prop_item:Nn \aaa {name}
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

The output does not show the space between "Alfréd" and "Rényi". I suspect this is due to `\ExplSyntaxOn` making LaTeX ignore space. I am stuck here. Any ideas?

Comment: Please use more the appropiate naming scheme for your variables, i.e. `\l_jaeya_name_prop`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Either use `\space` or `~`, otherwise spaces are gobbled in `expl3` regime.

I also changed the 'wrong' name of the `\prop` - list variable according to the `expl3` naming convention, i.e. `\l_jaeya_name_prop`, for example.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{expl3}

\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\prop_new:N \l_jaeya_name_prop
\prop_put:Nnn \l_jaeya_name_prop {name} {Alfr\'ed\space R\'enyi}
\prop_put:Nnn \l_jaeya_name_prop {othername} {Arthur~Gumby}
\prop_item:Nn \l_jaeya_name_prop {name}~and~\prop_item:Nn \l_jaeya_name_prop {othername}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

A better way is to store and retrieve the content with a wrapper:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{expl3}


\ExplSyntaxOn
\prop_new:N \l_jaeya_name_prop

\cs_new:Npn \storename #1#2{% The % isn't necessary, just for convenience for more complicated macros to remember where which bracket starts. 
  \prop_put:Nnn \l_jaeya_name_prop {#1} {#2}
}

\cs_new:Npn \retrievename #1{%
  \prop_item:Nn \l_jaeya_name_prop {#1}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\storename{name}{Alfr\'ed R\'enyi}
\storename{othername}{Arthur Gumby}

\retrievename{name} and \retrievename{othername}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, now I get it: space is gobbled because I am *calling* the function inside `expl3`, not because it is defined in `expl3`. Calling it outside `expl3` then solves the problem.

Comment: @Jaeya: Yes, that's the trick. The `expl3` features are meant for simplifying the programming, but they shouldn't appear directly in the document body for direct typesetting.

Comment: That's what I was planning to do later, but I did that for easier testing... Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Jaeya: You're welcome. Happy TeXing (with `expl3`) ;-)

Comment: +1. In expl3 I'd rather use `\c_space_tl` instead of `\space`. (Of course that's only needed after macros. `~` is much clearer)